# What is the purpose of daemonic processes in python multiprocessing?

Tags: python, python-multiprocessing

In the Python multiprocessing module [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/multiprocessing.html?highlight=process#multiprocessing.Process.daemon), we can read:

```
When a process exits, it attempts to terminate all of its daemonic child processes.
```

What does this mean exactly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a [forum thread](https://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-list/2009-May/535765.html) explaining it: this `daemon` attribute is coming from the `Threading` module, where the process exits when there are only daemonic threads left.

In the case of multiprocessing, the main (parent) process will `join` non-daemonic processes, waiting for them to finish, whereas it will (try to) terminate the daemonic processes.

For ex, the following script will wait until the child process ends:

```py
import multiprocessing
import time

a = multiprocessing.Process(target=lambda: time.sleep(10))
a.start()

# Wait 10s...
```

Whereas the following script will terminate immediately:

```py
import multiprocessing
import time

a = multiprocessing.Process(target=lambda: time.sleep(10), daemon=True)
a.start()

# Immediate exit
```